# Code generator column in a list

Tags: list, metadata

Is it possible to create a column that will generate a code based on the value of another column and the number of items that are created for the same specific value.

For exemple:
column 1 = title
column 2 = choice A, B, or C
column 3 = metadata is an automatic code generated based on value of column 2.

For exemple :
 B_0004 if this is the 4th time that we create an item with choice B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculated columns can't go "vertically". You cannot create a calculated value that derives from another list item. You can only go "horizontally" meaning that you can only look at the data about the current item.

The only other way to do it would be with a workflow or event receiver.